# Which class to write in entity manager service in symfony2 and FOS?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to use FOSUserBUndleBUndle

The xml class is

```
<service id="fos_user.entity_manager" 
         factory-service="doctrine" 
         factory-method="getEntityManager" 
         class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" 
         public="false">
                <argument>%fos_user.model_manager_name%</argument>
</service>
```

I want to know which class i have to write in

```
%fos_user.model_manager_name%
```

Basically i am just converting all xml files to yml files and make my custom bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's the name of the entity manager. If leaving blank it uses the standard entity manager

```
//File: vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry.php
    /**
    * Gets a named entity manager.
    *
    * @param string $name The entity manager name (null for the default one)
    *
    * @return EntityManager
    */
    public function getEntityManager($name = null)
    {
        if (null === $name) {
            $name = $this->defaultEntityManager;
        }

        if (!isset($this->entityManagers[$name])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Doctrine EntityManager named "%s" does not exist.', $name));
        }

        return $this->container->get($this->entityManagers[$name]);
    }
```